# Matlab: All combinations of binary matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary, permutation

I am looking for a simple way to get all combinations of an binary matrix. I tried already the function `perms()` but did not get a proper result.

I have for example an matrix N x N filled up with 1 and -1. With N=2 there would be 2^4 possible combinations of 1 and -1 like

```
       (1 1)          (1  1)          (-1 -1)
M(1) = (1 1) , M(2) = (1 -1) , M(3) = ( 1  1) and so on...
```

When I use perms() I don't get for example the first matrix.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can represent all numbers between `0` and `2^(N^2)-1` as binary numbers, and then reshape:

```
N = 2;
v = (1:2^(N^2))-1;
A = dec2bin(v)' - '0'; %'// Or use: decimalToBinaryVector(v)';
A(A==0) = -1;
A = reshape(A,N,N,2^(N^2));
```

Comment: Seems good to me,except the typo on first line (`2^N-1` instead of `2^N²-1`). Plus I'd point out that this approach doesn't force you to store all of these combinations in memory, as it gives a 1:1 correspondance between your matrices and `0:2^N²-1`, meaning if you just need to get one of these matrices at random for example, you can just pick a number and then apply the equivalence

Comment: @NKN in your case you need to remove some duplicate matrices; the code gives a 2x2x24 matrix for `A`. (Seems like an easy fix to me). In case of this answer, no idea, it does indeed deliver you all 16 possibilities for a 2x2 matrix containing 1 and -1.

Comment: @NKN: in your answer, the number of `1`s and `-1`s is fixed.

Comment: It seems that `decimalToBinaryVector` is specific to the Data Acquisition Toolbox. I believe you should be able to do the same with `A=(dec2bin(v)-'0').';` though.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I remembered there's a function to do it, but for some reason the search in Matlab's doc gave me `decimalToBinaryVector`. I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: There's also `de2bi` for later versions of MATLAB, and in addition to @BillBokeey's observation about the upper end of the range (which has not been corrected in your code), you should start the range at `0`.

Comment: @beaker The range starts at zero. The comment was about a typo in the text (and not in the code). Just run it and see...

Answer (score -1):

A simple hack is as follows:

```
v = [1 -1 1 -1];
P = perms(v);
for ii = 1:size(P,1)
    A = reshape(P(ii,:),2,2)
end
```

which results in:

```
A =

    -1    -1
     1     1

...
```

Still there are some identical matrices in the result which should be removed.

Comment: With your approach I do not get matrices with more than two 1 or -1.

Comment: You get only matrices with a combination of two `-1`s and two `1`s. To remove the duplicates I suggest a line `P = unique(P,'rows')` to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

I think that I found an solution to my problem

```
L = 2;
N = L^2;
v = cell(N,1);
for k = 1:N
    v{k} = linspace(-1,1,2);
end

ne=numel(v);
x=cell(ne,1);
[x{1:ne,1}]=ndgrid(v{end:-1:1});
p=reshape(cat(ne+1,x{:}),[],ne);

F = cell(length(p),1);
for k=1:length(p)
    F{k} = reshape(p(k,:),L,L);
end
```

Comment: Two things: please do not use `clear all` in SO codes, as people tend to copy these codes in their own and a `clear` call messes up everything. Second: `p` is a 65536x16 double, which seems a bit large for your permutations. All desired permutations are there, but way too often. You went a bit overboard with your dimensions I think.

Comment: Also: `v` is just a 16x1 cell with 16 times the same matrix: `[-1 1]`. That entire loop is just a difficult way of writing those two numbers. (As a side note, I did not vote on this answer)

Comment: I did downvote the answer now, because whilst you did remove the `clear`, that was not the main point of this solution being wrong. Just run it and see for yourself that `v` contains 16 matrices all being `[-1 1]`, and `p` is way larger than you'd need. This makes the answer unusable.

Comment: @Adriaan Now, it should be right. Can you have a look?

Comment: It's correct now, but you still have that weird assignment for `v`, see a previous comment as explanation. This results in all cells of `x` containing duplicate matrices, making this code not very efficient.  Also I'd suggest not using a cell for `F`, but a 3D array as such: `F(:,:,k) = reshape(p(k,:),L,L);` All in all it's working, but not pretty nor efficient. I removed the downvote though, as it does work.